# Expected expression before ']' token?

Tags: c

I have the following line which sends the arguments `args[]` and `length` to a method called `largest`.

```
  printf("Largest is: %d \n", largest(args[], length));
```

When i try to run this i get the following error:

`error: expected expression before ']' token`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you need to place an integer between the operator square brakets, or otherwise don't specify the square brackets :

```
printf("Largest is: %d \n", largest(&args[0], length));
```

or

```
printf("Largest is: %d \n", largest(args, length));
```

Keep in mind that `args[0]` is the same as `*(args + 0)` but `args[]` will give an error because it needs a number to sum ...

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf("Largest is: %d \n", largest(args, length));
```

just remove the '[]', because args is a pointer and that's what the function is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want the pointer of the array, so pass in `largest(args, length)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an array like that. You have to pass the pointer to the array (first item):

```
printf("Largest is: %d \n", largest(args, length));
```